# if current field value greater than in javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to add a second condition to a js function

original condition

```
if (content.length==elmnt.maxLength)
```

new condition

```
if (content.length==elmnt.maxLength && current form field value > 1400)
```

how do I code "current form field value > 1400" properly in javascript?

Full original code:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function jumpField(elmnt,content)
{
if (content.length==elmnt.maxLength)
    {
    next=elmnt.tabIndex
    if (next<document.forms[0].elements.length)
        {
        document.forms[0].elements[next].focus()
        }
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, because it's not clear what you're passing in, but `parseInt(content) > 1400` might do you.

Comment: Surely the *slightest* bit of research would have shown you how to do this.

Comment: T.J. I am modifying a small script in js and could not figure out how to write my condition. Thought asking wouldn't arm, instead of wasting hours researching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to achieve.
Are you looking for `parseInt()` to convert a string value? Like:

```
parseInt(document.forms[0].elements[next].value) > 1400
```

Comment: You don't even *really* need the `parseInt`, though using it (with a radix) is best practice.

Comment: ^^ Radix! Specially when coming from user input. `parseInt(01500) > 1400 // false, oops`

Comment: @elclanrs: Absolutely. :-) But technically that (if it were a string) would be an invalid numeric string for `parseInt`, though I understand Opera's engine still allows it, in variance with the ES5 spec which specifically disallows octal auto-detect in `parseInt` (not even optionally as with numeric literals from Annex B, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Yes, it was the simplest example I could think of. Plus not so many people "use strict".

Comment: @elclanrs: Right, but the ES5 clarifications of `parseInt` aren't limited to strict mode.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Here is my new code:  `if ((content.length==elmnt.maxLength) || (parseInt(document.forms[0].elements[0].value) > 1800))`